# Sign In With Email and Password method in Firebase has a bug

Tags: firebase

I have one account including email and password in firebase authenication. But when I use this code, the firebase always return "Sign in successfully", even when I input wrong email and password. I look fowarding to your help. Thank you very much!

```
private void signIn(){
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isComplete()){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sign in successfull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sign in failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using isComplete which will always be true since you're running it under onComplete. Use isSuccessful instead.

```
if(task.isSuccessful()){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sign in successfull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Sign in failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. According your suggestion, I resolved it. Once again, thank you! :D